# Is there away to remove increment labels on the y axis in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I am plotting three years of data on a scatterplot in ggplot2, with years as the y-axis.  The axis is scaling so that the tick mark labels are "2015.5, 2016, 2016.5 … etc." and I need them to just be "2016 2017 2018".  I have tried to use the scale_y_discrete function.

Here is my code

```
x <- (plot <- ggplot(NULL, aes(sos, year)) + 
  geom_jitter(data = epic, aes(col = "EPIC")) +
  geom_jitter(data = landsat, aes(col = "Landsat")) +
  geom_jitter(data = pheno, aes(col = "PhenoCam")))
x + labs(title = "Start of Season Comparison",
       x = "DOY",
       y = "Year")
```

and here is the current
[scatterplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrH8A.jpg)

Thank you!

Comment: What did ggplot say or do when you used `scale_y_discrete`?

Comment: you could try using `scale_y_continuous` and setting the `breaks` argument

Comment: @Edward when I use `scale_y_discrete` it removes the y-label entirely.  I added this code to the end of the script above `scale_y_discrete(breaks=c("2016", "2017", "2018"), labels=c("2016", "2017", "2018"))` and also tried it without breaks.

Comment: @JonathanV.Solórzano using `scale_y_continuous` and setting the breaks argument gives me the error: "Error in r[i1] - r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L)] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator".  Perhaps I am setting the breaks wrong? I am a new programmer...here is what I used `scale_y_continuous(breaks=c("2016", "2017", "2018"))`

Comment: Try setting the breaks without the "" (quotes), like `breaks = c(2016, 2017, 2018)`

Comment: @JonathanV.Solórzano This worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked to see the year variable is numeric ? If that is numeric then I think Solorzanos solutions should work

Comment: It is numeric. `scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(2016, 2017, 2018))` worked! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to change year as  factors, but I am not sure if this is correct way of doing it or not.

ggplot(NULL, aes(sos, as.factor(year))) +